# UIScrollview width does not Scale equally to iPhone size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uikit

I am trying to create a full-screen scroll view that scrolls through an array of objects. In the story board, I just have a scrollview anchored to the edges of the superview so its full screen. A new view with a text field is created for each object in the array (**see code**).

The scroll view works perfectly on the the 6s Size, but when it runs on the SE simulator, I get different results. The scroll view is completely screwed up (**See Below**)

[image]  [image]

Below are my scrollView Settings: [image]

Below is my code. Its goal was to create a view for each object and display its text.

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

//Create your connection from your storyboard
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

// This is an array of views that will be appended to the scroll view later.
// These can be images or whatever want
var mainViews = [UIView]()

// This is an array of objects that are modeled off the SampleObjcet class we created earlier.
// They all contain diffrent strings to display. We will add the text as they are created
var arrayOfSampleObjects = [
    SampleObject(sampleText: "Page 1"),SampleObject(sampleText: "Page 2"),
    SampleObject(sampleText: "Page 3"),SampleObject(sampleText: "Page 4"),
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // contentWidth is a varible that controlls the width of the scroll view
    // This variabel grows each time a view is added
    var contentWidth: CGFloat = 0.0

    // scrollviewWidth & scrollviewHeight hold the sizes so we can use them to 
    // calculate the diffrent views later
    let scrollviewWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width
    let scrollviewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height

    // This is where the magic happens. 
    // This for loop goes through the array of objects and create views for each object.
    for object in 0..<arrayOfSampleObjects.count {

        // textToShowInformation is a label made to show the text from the diffrent objects.
        // Sets up text properties
        let textToShowInformation = UILabel()
        textToShowInformation.text = arrayOfSampleObjects[object].sampleText // Goes through the arrayOfSampleObjects infromation
        textToShowInformation.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textToShowInformation.textAlignment = .center

        // viewToShowInformation is the view that wil be created for each object
        // for example, if there are 50 objects, there will be 50 views.
        let viewToShowInformation = UIView()

        // This adds the diffrent views to the mainViews array to be displayed
        mainViews.append(viewToShowInformation)

        // ERROR
        // come back to this.... the calculations only work for 6s -_-
        var newX: CGFloat = 0.0

        //object in an index so if its object 4,
        //it will be 4x' s as wide...i think...
        newX = scrollviewWidth * CGFloat(object)


        contentWidth += newX - scrollviewWidth
        scrollView.addSubview(viewToShowInformation)
        viewToShowInformation.addSubview(textToShowInformation)
        viewToShowInformation.frame = CGRect(x: newX, y:0, width: scrollviewWidth, height: scrollviewHeight)

        // Constraints for the text fields. Center Everything...
        textToShowInformation.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewToShowInformation.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        textToShowInformation.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewToShowInformation.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    // Sets up the scroll view properties
    scrollView.bounces = true // allows views to bounce past the scrollview width. change to personal preferance
    // Below controlls the width size of the scrollview,I think the problem could lie here too
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(arrayOfSampleObjects.count), height:scrollviewHeight)
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = false // important
}
}
```

Everything works for the 6-6s, but when it runs on the SE, the text is not centered. *The text is anchored to the middle of the view this is added*

If you cant see it clearly here, here is the link to the repo so you can test it out: [object_controlled_scrollview](https://github.com/marquavious/object_controlled_scrollview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing the following block of code inside `viewDidLoad`-

```
let scrollviewWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width
let scrollviewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height
```

Your autoLayout has not been implemented yet. So initially your *scrollViewWidth* and *scrollViewHeight* gets set to whatever size you designed your project in, inside the storyboard.

Try moving your entire block of code that sets up the `UIScrollView` to either `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidAppear`

**OR**

You can try force calling `view.layoutIfNeeded()` after `super.viewDidLoad()`

Comment: I haven't tried the other methods, but putting it in the viewDidAppear fixed it! thank you!

Comment: Make sure you only do it once in `viewDidAppear` as that function gets called multiple times!

Comment: calling `view.layoutIfNeeded()` worked and I will use that instead! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to below line of code:

```
scrollView.setNeedsLayout()
scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, however, this answer doesn't work.